# pdf file not loading from website

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I open a pdf file that has been saved on the server on the client side. I was creating a process to do this but it has not worked
`(System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfFilePath + pdffileName);`). 
I need to open this file on the client side as they need to send it the label print.

Comment: Post any error messages, also what do you mean by "has not worked"

Comment: there where no error messages as nothing was happening. I had been using the process.start to open the pdf file locally while I was still developing when I published my site I tried to load the pdf file from the site and now nothing is happening. I am not to sure what I could do to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to write the file into the response. You try to open it on the server.

```
Context.Response.Buffer = false;
        FileStream inStr = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        long byteCount; inStr = File.OpenRead(pdfFilePath + pdffileName);
        while ((byteCount = inStr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
            if (Context.Response.IsClientConnected) {
                Context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                Context.Response.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
[.NET MVC FileResult equivalent in Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088962/net-mvc-fileresult-equivalent-in-web-forms)

The response marked as answer should also fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to stream the file to the client (as the answer above indicates), or save it to a location under the site and give the user a link to it. You shouldn't need to start a process - link to the file and the browser will figure out what application to use to open it.

(You MAY need to set up a MIME type in IIS)

For example, assuming you save in the site under PDFFiles:

```
HyperLink pdfLink = new Hyperlink();
pdfLink.NavigateUrl = "~/PDFFiles/" + filename
```

Then add the link to your page controls. (Or you can hard-code the link in the ASPX file and set the NavigateUrl attribute in codebehind - however you want to do it)